# Simple question re: Passing a parameterized datatype in SML

Tags: sml

I just spent an embarrassing amount of time figuring out that if you're passing a parameterized datatype into a higher-order function in SML, it needs to be in brackets `()`; so, for example:

`fun f1 p = f2 p` will work when called like this (for example): `f1(Datatype(parameter))` but will not work if called like `f1 Datatype(parameter)`. I'm sure there's a very simple reason why, but I'm not quite clear. Is it something like, the datatype and parameter are "seen" as 2 things by the function if not in brackets? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's important to realize how functions work in SML. Functions take a single argument, and return a single value. This is very easy to understand but it's very often practically necessary for a function to take more than one value as input. There are two ways of achieving this:

**Tuples**

A function can take one value that contains multiple values in the form of a tuple. This is very common in SML. Consider for instance:

```
fun add (x, y) = x + y
```

Here `(x, y)` is a tuple inferred to be composed of two `int`s.

**Currying**

A function takes one argument and returns one value. But functions *are* values in SML, so a function can return a function.

```
fun add x = fn y => x + y
```

Or just:

```
fun add x y = x + y
```

This is common in OCaml, but less common in SML.

**Function Application**

Function application in SML takes the form of `functionName argument`. When a tuple is involved, it looks like: `functionName (arg1, arg2)`. But the space can be elided: `functionName(arg1, arg2)`.

Even when tuples are not involved, we can put parentheses around any value. So calling a function with a single argument can look like: `functionName argument`, `functionName (argument)`, or `functionName(argument)`.

**Your Question**

```
f1(Datatype(parameter))
```

This parses the way you expect.

```
f1 Datatype(parameter)
```

*This* parses as `f1 Datatype parameter`, which is a curried function `f1` applied to the arguments `Datatype` and `parameter`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the parentheses around `Datatype` are completely redundant, i.e., it's completely equivalent to `Datatype parameter`. I mean, even in the construction `f1(Datatype(parameter))`, it should be `f1 (Datatype parameter)`. +1 otherwise

Comment: thanks so much, yes this is basically as I was thinking. Just a note, my parameter was in brackets just because I was using a datatype with a tuple parameter as an example.

Comment: @ahpto you should upvote and mark this answer as accepted if the information contained within helped your, which it seems it did.

Comment: Ok I don't have enough reputation to upvote and I didn't know I could mark an answer as accepted but thanks for the heads up

Comment: If you're unsure on how to accept an answer:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419